# PHP - Is this code guaranteed to stop if the condition isn't met?

Tags: php, exception

I am only learning Exceptions and error reporting, and I am trying to understand behaviours of try/catch and perhaps other methods that I don't know yet. I have code like this:

```
function nameless(....) {
    if(!$condition) {
        throw new Exception('Condition not met');
    }
    [someCode ...]
    return $result;
}
```

I want to make sure that `someCode` only executes if the condition is met. Would a structure like this guarantee that it?

Before talking about putting the rest of the code in an `else` block, or other methods, I want to know if there is some way to execute `nameless()` in a way that would continue its execution after it throws the exception.

Once I know that, I would like to know if there are better/worse ways of doing things and if this particular example is poor or it's one of a hundred equally valid ways to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the exception will halt execution of that function at the throw point. Look into the try/catch notes at http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: On the question "_is there are better/worse ways"_, the answer must be: It totally depends on the situation.

Comment: Yeah, at that point the question becomes "_primarily opinion-based_"

Comment: Have you actually tested your code before asking :)?

Comment: Some people love throwing exceptions all over the place in any situation, making the code 80% try/catch while some people never use them.

Comment: What kind of condition we're talking about here? if it's a type check then there's probably a better way.

Comment: Maciej - yes, it halted of course, I wanted to know if there are some ways to execute the code that would _not_ halt it. It seems there isn't. In my case it checks if the MySQL table passed exists in the active database. Thanks everyone for informative answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will stop. The behavior is defined [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

> When an exception is thrown, code following the statement will not be executed, and PHP will attempt to find the first matching catch block. If an exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal Error will be issued with an "Uncaught Exception ..." message, unless a handler has been defined with set_exception_handler().

Based on the definition and purpose of exceptions, the function should not continue after an exception, and you shouldn't look for a way to force that to happen.

If you have some code that must be executed even after an exception is thrown, you should not include it in the function, but instead enclose the function in a `try/catch`, with the necessary code in a `finally` block.